# System requirements: What is the lightest impacting ubuntu flavor?

Tags: intel-graphics, intel, acer, system-requirements

I have been looking for a Linux alternative to windows due to the OS constantly eating up my system's memory and CPU usage, and i'm somewhat familiar with Ubuntu systems, but i want to know what flavor might be the best for my light-weight system.

Here are my specs:

```
Acer Aspire A114-32-C1YA
Processor Manufacturer  Intel®
Processor Type Celeron®
Processor Model N4000
Processor Speed 1.10 GHz
Processor Core Dual-core (2 Core™)

Display & Graphics
Graphics Controller Manufacturer Intel®
Graphics Controller Model UHD Graphics 600
Graphics Memory Technology DDR4 SDRAM
Graphics Memory Accessibility Shared
Standard Memory 4 GB
Memory Technology DDR4 SDRAM

Storage
Optical Drive Type No
Flash Memory Capacity 64 GB
```

Please let me know what flavors i should consider, thanks!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586003/find-the-lightest-desktop-environment

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu is generally considered the lightest Ubuntu distribution

you can download it here: https://lubuntu.net/downloads/